# flutter) Firebase Phone Auth's "verificationCompleted" does not work on Android devices

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I authenticate through firebase phone auth, and on Android, I want to authenticate automatically through "verificationComplete".
However, the function "codeSent" is called instead of "verificationCompleted".

```
  Future<void> _sendingCode(String phoneNum, BuildContext context) async {
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

return await auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
  phoneNumber: phoneNum,
  forceResendingToken: _forceResendingToken,

  verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) async {
    logger.d('verificationCompleted - $credential');

    // Sign the user in (or link) with the auto-generated credential
    await auth.signInWithCredential(credential).then((value) async {

      // next page 
      context.read<PageController>().animateToPage(2,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);
    }).catchError((e) => logger.w(e));
  },

  codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
    logger.w('timeout');
  },

  codeSent: (String verificationId, int? forceResendingToken) {
    logger.d("$phoneNum send code");

    _verificationId = verificationId;
    _forceResendingToken = forceResendingToken;
  },

  verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException error) {
    logger.e("Error: $error");
  },
);
```

}

Can I know the cause of this problem?

Answer (score 1):

`onVerificationCompleted()` will only be called when the phone number has been verified without any input from the user. To do what you are trying, you should be sending your action inside `onCodeSent()` instead.

Obtain phone number from user

- Call `PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(auth)` (as you are already) to send the pin to the user
- `onCodeSent()` is called, with the verification ID and a resending token.
- Inside of `onCodeSent()`, create an method to launch the "pin input screen" with the verification ID.
- Get a pin from the user and then combine it with the verification ID by calling `PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, userInput)`
- Use that credential to sign in the user using `signInWithCredential(credential).`

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement both functions. `onVerificationCompleted` function not working all the time.

More details about `onVerificationCompleted` [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#onverificationcompletedphoneauthcredential)

Add the same logic inside your `codeSent` method.